# How to carry out an operation on a column returned by Unix awk command only if it's numeric?

Tags: unix, awk

I have an input file which looks as below pattern wise :

```
hi this is the first line
this is the second line 
...
more lines 
... 

    Name Number  Position 
    
    Bob   1      Employee
    
    Sam   21     Manager
    
    Joe   25     Employee
```

I want to ensure that the Number column is having numbers (or digits) in ascending order. I am using below awk command but it is always giving me output as 'OK' even if the order is not ascending:

```
awk 'BEGIN {res = "OK"}
     NR > 1 && $2 ~ /[[:digit:]]+/ && $2 <= prev {res = "Fail"; exit}
     {prev = $2}
     END {print res}'  file
```

Any help to make it work will be great.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `$1` and not `$2`?

Comment: The number column is the second column but you are referencing the first?

Comment: ^^ and in addition, on the second line `prev = "Number"`. You might want to handle `NR==2` like specially/separately.

Comment: sorry typo, it is $2 , I have corrected

Comment: Why are there empty lines between your lines? and you are on a Linux or DOS environment?

Comment: Linux environment

Comment: wrt `I want to ensure that the Number column is having numbers (or digits) in ascending order` is a very vague requirement - 1) which is it to be, numbers `($i+0 == $i)` or digits `($i ~ /^[0-9]+$/)`? 2) what do you do if it's not what you want - empty the field, delete the line, report an error, output nothing, output a fixed file, etc? 3) What do you want to do if they aren't in ascending order - delete non-conforming limes, print an error, etc.? Can `more lines`, etc. contain "numbers" in the second field and do you care if the script validates those lines? Can they contain `Number`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN { res="OK" } $0 ~ /Name/ && $0 ~ /Number/ && $0 ~ /Position/ { proc=1;next } proc==1 && $2 <= prev { res="FAIL" } proc==1 { prev=$2 } END { print res }' file
```

When the line contains "Number", "Name", or "Position" set a marker proc to 1 and skip using next Then where the second column is less than or equal to the variable prev and proc is 1, set res to "FAIL". Set prev to the second field in all instances where proc is 1. At the end, print res.

Comment: well the first line is not the column that I am showing...there could be many lines before it, I just showed a snippet.

Comment: This is tested with the sample provided. If there is any additional information in the file, please post a sample in the post.

Comment: Done in the post

Comment: OK, I've amended the solution

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
hi this is the first line
this is the second line 
...
more lines 
... 

    Name Number  Position 
    
    Bob   1      Employee
    
    Sam   21     Manager
    
    Joe   25     Employee
```

I would do something along these lines:

```
$  awk '$2+0!=$2 || NF!=3 {next}
        !flag {prev=$2; flag=1; next}
        prev>$2 {bad=1; exit}
        {prev=$2}
        END{if (bad) print "FAIL"; else print "SUCCESS"}' file
```

Prints `"SUCCESS"`

Now try with:

```
$ cat file
hi this is the first line
this is the second line 
...
more lines 
... 

    Name Number  Position 
    
    Bob   1      Employee
    
    Sam   21     Manager
    
    Joe   20     Employee
```

Prints `"FAIL"`

Comment: it always prints success for me, sometimes said flag event not found

Comment: @A.G.Progm.Enthusiast: Both answers here work on the examples you gave. You clearly are not fully describing the file that you are working with.